# Open Side Menu Default On Condition

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Working with the Ionic Framework, I would like to open the side menu by default on condition that a specific variable is not null.

My current method is as follows:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (User.pref == null) {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft([true]);
    }
});
```

I believe this doesn't work as the conditional is firing off before the menu is loaded (but after the 'platform' is ready).

EDIT:

The full code is here, using an alert statement I can indeed verify that the nested code is being executed.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicPlatform, Colleges, User) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  if (User.pref == null) {
    alert('it is closed by default ' + $ionicSideMenuDelegate.isOpen());
    // output: it is null udefined
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft([true]);
    alert('it should be open ' + $ionicSideMenuDelegate.isOpen());
    // output: it should be open undefined
  }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try calling `$ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();` using a `$timeout` of 0.